# Prove that 100...500...1 (100 zeros in each group) is not a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, exponentiation

How can i prove that 100...00500...001 [with 100 zeros in each group ( ...  is 100 zeros)]is not a perfect cube? I tried symmetric features of the number but could not figure out anything related. Any ideas please tell me.

Comment: Look at the number mod n for a few values of n and see what you find out.

Comment: I don't understand what $100\ldots 500\ldots 0$ means.

Comment: @Tony: The number is $10^{202}+5\cdot10^{101}+1$: a $1$ followed by $100$ zeroes, a $5$, another $100$ zeroes, and a $1$.

Comment: Following up on John's suggestion. Try $n$ a prime that is congruent to $1\pmod 6$. Only one third of the residue classes are then cubic residues. Hint: a prime $<20$ will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well thanks to elaqqad i got an answer.
Its just that the digital index of cubes are 1,8,9 in a pattern.
ex- digital index of 1 cube = 1 
    ""             "" 2 ""  = 8
    ""             "" 3""   = 9 (27 - 2+7)
     ""           ""   4 "" = 1 (64 - 6+4)
    ""            ""  5  "" = 8  (1+2+5)
    ""            "" 6  ""  = 9 (2+1+6)
but the digital index of the above number is 7 (1+5+1)
so simply it's not a cube.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** : Every cube is either $0, 1,$ or $8 \mod 9$. Your number is equal to $7 \mod 9$